# Open safari tab group from terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, safari

I want to open a particular safari tab group through the terminal

I'm aware that

```
open -a safari
```

would open the safari app but it creates a new blank tab group

and

```
open -a safari <url>
```

will open a particular url in safari

But I want to open a particular tab group in safari or the last opened tab group.

Comment: There are two possible options 1) Safari -> Preferences -> General -> Safari Opens With. 2) To combine terminal command with applescript, i dont have an exact applescript just an idea towards right direction: "open -a safari & osascript -e 'tell application "Safari"' -e 'YOUR CUSTOM SAFARI BEHAVIOUR' -e 'end tell'"

Comment: Unfortunately Safari tab groups aren’t scriptable, so this can’t be done, except maybe via GUI scripting which will be more trouble than it’s worth.